# Changing Django code logs me out of application

Tags: python, django, memory

I am new to Django. I wrote a basic application. When I test it, every small change I make in the Python code logs me out from localhost.

This happens when I use this cache backend:

```
'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
```

but does not when I use this one:

```
'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
```

Is there a way that I can continue using locmem but not get logged out?

Comment: Which files do you change that cause this? I can't remember the last time I was logged out during a coding session.

Comment: In general almost any code related to Django

Comment: Something else is going on with your code aside from the caching backend, if you're being logged out on any change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that your [`SESSION_ENGINE` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-engine) is set to `cache`, and that you're using the development server.

If so, then the behavior you're seeing makes perfect sense. When you change your Python code, the development server automatically restarts, losing all the data in memory. Since that includes the cache, which includes the session information, you lose that too, forcing everyone to login all over again.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-sessions) mentions this:

> **Warning**
>
> You should only use cache-based sessions if you’re using the Memcached cache backend. The local-memory cache backend doesn’t retain data long enough to be a good choice.

Since you want to keep the `LocMemCache`, you should use a different session backend. A simple approach might be the cookie-based backend, but check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine) to see all your options.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was lucky to figure it out on my own as well :)

Comment: Additionally, I am getting logged out even if I do not change the code, but move from one page to another. It is not reproducible 100% of the times, but maybe around 40%. I guess it is because the cache is getting full and so the session data is deleted from cache. Any suggestions to debug this?

Comment: Actually I figured out that the issue is because I am using local memory and the session is getting removed from cache

Comment: Do you know if the localmem size can be increased?